# Add pin on click Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maps

I want to add a new pin on clicking on the map using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.
After searching , I found that I have to use TKCustomMap plugin .. but it didn't show on the map .. just empty area
and this is my code

```
   double lit = 2.394;// double.Parse(Center.CenterLocationX);
   double longt = 43.2352;// double.Parse(Center.CenterLocationY);
   TK.CustomMap.Position position = new TK.CustomMap.Position(lit, longt);
   TK.CustomMap.MapSpan span = TK.CustomMap.MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, TK.CustomMap.Distance.FromMiles(0.5));

   TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMap map = new TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMap(span);
   map.IsShowingUser = true;
   map.MapType = TK.CustomMap.MapType.Street;
   TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin pin = new TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin()
   {
        //Address = "Test",
        //Label = "Test",
        Position = position,
        IsDraggable = true
        //Type = PinType.SearchResult
    };
    map.MapClicked += (x, y) =>
    {
        SharedTools.MakeToast("Clicked");
    };
    //map.Pins.Add(pin);
    map.Pins = new List<TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin>() { pin };

    map.MoveToMapRegion(span);
    layout.Content = map;
```

I want to solve this, or any other idea to add pin on click

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in my demo, i got the result like the following screenshot(If you cannot see the band of `google`, you should check the `API_KEY`, if it is correct.)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="API_KEY" />
```

[image]

Then i changed the `lit`  to 37, `longt`  to -122 and add pin on click.I can see the map and get the following result. Please check your `lit` and `longt`, if the value is legal

[image]

There is my code.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMap map;
    TK.CustomMap.Position position;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //37,-122
        double lit = 37;// double.Parse(Center.CenterLocationX);
        double longt = -122;// double.Parse(Center.CenterLocationY);
        position = new TK.CustomMap.Position(lit, longt);
        TK.CustomMap.MapSpan span = TK.CustomMap.MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, TK.CustomMap.Distance.FromMiles(0.5));
        map = new TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMap(span);
        map.IsShowingUser = true;
        map.MapType = TK.CustomMap.MapType.Street;
        map.MapClicked += OnMapClicked;
        Content = map;
    }
    private void OnMapClicked(object sender, TKGenericEventArgs<Position> e)
    {
        TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin pin = new TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin()
        {
            //Address = "Test",
            //Label = "Test",
            Position = position
        ,
            IsDraggable = true
            //Type = PinType.SearchResult
        };
        
        map.Pins = new List<TK.CustomMap.TKCustomMapPin>() { pin };
        
    }
}
```

Here is my demo.Hope this can help you.

https://github.com/851265601/TKGoogleMapsDemo

Comment: Thank you .. because It was urgent, I've used Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps, and this library solved the problem .. I will try your using solution .. thank you again :)

Comment: Just used Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps instead of Xamarin.Forms.Maps